# How to display sub categories under products page using woocommerce with mystile theme

Tags: plugins

I have been trying to display my product subcategories after you click on the parent category but to no avail. It simply shows all my products for instance: Main product- Pacifier Clips, Subcat- NFL Pacifier clips, but once you click on main product(Pacifier Clip) it shows all Pacifier clips from every category without giving you the option to choose which category. I have tried the settings under catalog in woocommerce but with no success, I have ensured that my subcategories are linked to my parent category. I'm all out of ideas of what to do. I would be willing to add code to resolve the problem but am not sure which php file to edit under woocommerce. Anyone have any idea?

Site address: www.innovativehouseholddesigns.com

Comment: Does that means when you click on paci-clips category, you want to see all the categories under paci-clips, rather than product list ?

Comment: exactly that's what I would like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Woo-commerce Product Category Page. Find the category **PACI-CLIPS**, click on *edit*. And from the edit page, Set `Display type` to `Subcategories`.

Comment: Man, I cant believe that! So stinkin simple. Beautiful! Thanks again!

Comment: great, you can mark is answer as correct, do an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure there is at least one product in the subcategories or they will not show up when you view that parent category!